# jquery mobile theme roller hover

Tags: jquery, css

I rolled a theme using jQuery mobile's theme roller and am now reading through the generated code. I noticed that jQuery.mobile provides :hover functionality. If jquery.mobile is used for mobile phones then what purpose does styling the :hover functionality serve. Are all smart phones not touch screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have answered that jQuery.mobile clients are not necessarily SmartPhones but I think this article [Are Hover Events Extinct?](http://designshack.net/articles/css/are-hover-events-extinct/) probably explains it much more completely...

Hope that helps.